# How do I pass a list as changing condition in an array?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say that I have an numpy array `a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]` and I want to change everything else but 1,2 and 3 to 0. With a list `b = [1,2,3]` a tried a[a not in b] = 0, but Python does not accept this. Currently I'm using a for loop like this:

```
c = a.unique()    

for i in c:
   if i not in b:
      a[a == i] = 0
```

Which works very slowly (Around 900 different values in a 3D array around the size of 1000x1000x1000) and doesn't fell like the optimal solution for numpy. Is there a more optimal way doing it in numpy?

Comment: In that SPECIFIC example, you could say `a[a > 3] = 0`.  Does that work with your real data?

Comment: Hello Tim, no it was just an example. The values will be random. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.isin()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) to create a boolean mask to use as an index:

```
np.isin(a, b)
# array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False])
```

Use `~` to do the opposite:

```
~np.isin(a, b)
# array([False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```

Using this to index the original array lets you assign zero to the specific elements:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3])

a[~np.isin(a, b)] = 0

print(a)
# [1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0]
```